# Disable macOS Sonoma Text Insertion Point (Cursor) / Caps-lock Indicator

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma

Is there any way to disable the new text cursor in macOS Sonoma? The caps lock indicator is kind of distracting.

Comment: And all we needed is for Apple to add a simple setting in keyboard preferences to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Thanks to stephancasas for the explanation and the solution.
Another way of implementing it, from Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'redesigned_text_cursor:Enabled' bool false" /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist
```

Reboot for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 88):

Simplifying the code yet further, you can just do:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist redesigned_text_cursor -dict-add Enabled -bool NO
```

The folders will be created if not existing.

You'll still need a restart.

Comment: Perfect. One simple command that gets the job done. Can be easily integrated with  machine setup scripts ala https://github.com/kevinSuttle/macOS-Defaults

Comment: I had to revert this change because it caused my text cursor to disappear in some UI elements. For example, when entering the title of a new calendar event. I'm running macOS 14.2 (23C64).

Comment: Along the same lines, Ulysses does not display a cursor at all in this mode. Apparently the custom shenanigans they had to do to make their text editor play nicely with the new cursor… don't play nicely with disabling the new cursor.

Comment: What script do you run to revert the changes. Cant seem to figure that part out

Comment: @Yusuf.I `sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist redesigned_text_cursor`

Answer (score 22):

The redesigned insertion point in macOS Sonoma can be disabled by setting an OS feature flag for `UIKit/redesigned_text_cursor/Enabled`. You can use the JXA script below to create the PLIST with the required values. Just copy everything into **Script Editor**, change the language to *JavaScript*, and press play:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript

const App = Application.currentApplication();
App.includeStandardAdditions = true;

const kCFPrefsFeatureFlagsDir = '/Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain';
const kCFPrefsFeatureEnabledKey = 'Enabled';

const kUIKitDomainPrefsTemporaryPath = '/tmp/UIKit.plist';
const kUIKitRedesignedTextCursorKey = 'redesigned_text_cursor';

function run(_) {
  const dict = $.NSMutableDictionary.new;

  const enabled = $.NSMutableDictionary.new;
  enabled.setValueForKey(false, kCFPrefsFeatureEnabledKey);

  dict.setValueForKey(enabled, kUIKitRedesignedTextCursorKey);

  const error = $();
  dict.writeToURLError(
    $.NSURL.fileURLWithPath(kUIKitDomainPrefsTemporaryPath),
    error,
  );

  if (typeof error.js != 'undefined') {
    return `: ${error.localizedDescription}`;
  }

  return App.doShellScript(
    [
      `mkdir -p '${kCFPrefsFeatureFlagsDir}'`,
      `mv '${kUIKitDomainPrefsTemporaryPath}' '${kCFPrefsFeatureFlagsDir}'`,
    ].join(' && '),
    {
      administratorPrivileges: true,
    },
  ).length == 0 ? '' : '';
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this has fixed it. Reboot after. Not sure why half the internet has decided to be so bullish about it being a design feature! If you want to run it via terminal/command line, you can save the file as a js file, then use: `osascript whatever.js`

A password popup will appear, then show the smiley face if all goes well. As mentioned, reboot (maybe relog, reboot for good measure :)).

Comment: Yes! Thank you, @stephancasas. I asked this question some weeks ago over on Think Different. If you post an answer over there, even if it's just point here, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464717/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-text-cursor-color-in-macos-sonoma?noredirect=1#comment687561_464717

Comment: Bonus question: The cursor still retains its accent-based color in Safari. Happen to know of trick to disable it there as well?

Comment: I'm curious how you discovered such an obscure and specific filepath and pref keys.

Comment: @benwiggy, I attached lldb to the `CursorUIViewService` process and started looking for caps lock-related instructions. Apple uses pretty consistent naming patterns for their symbols, so if you know what you want to achieve, you can narrow-down to the likely procedures in pretty short order. As for what process I knew to look debug, I go into detail on that [here](https://twitter.com/stephancasas/status/1668186301558923265).

Answer (score 11):

You can try this to disable Input Source Switching Popup as of Dec 6, 2023:

1. Open Terminal app and type:

   ```bash
   defaults write kCFPreferencesAnyApplication TSMLanguageIndicatorEnabled 0
   ```
2. Press Return and restart your machine afterwards.

Comment: No need to restart, just restart each app.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle in

Onyx – Parameters – Misc. - Show the caps lock indicator

and Deeper – Misc. - Show the caps lock indicator

https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/applications.html

OnyX 4.5.5

• Added option to hide or show the caps lock indicator
https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx_release.html

Deeper 3.0.4

• Added option to hide or show the caps lock indicator

https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/deeper_release.html